# VB.NET Out of Memory Issue on ImageList

Tags: vb.net, listview, memory-management, imagelist

**EDITED:**
I'm getting an ***"Out of Memory"*** error by loading images to an ImageList even when I put `dispose()` or `End Using` after adding bitmap to ImageList.

Here's my code.

```
Function loadImage()
    Dim item As New ListViewItem

    imageList.ImageSize = New Size(45, 70)

    For Each value In arr
        If System.IO.File.Exists(value) Then
            Using img As New Bitmap(value)
                imageList.Images.Add(Image.FromHbitmap(img.GetHbitmap))
            End Using
            newListView.LargeImageList = imageList
            item = New ListViewItem(value)
            newListView.Items.Add(item)
            item.Name = value
            item.Tag = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(value)
            newListView.Items(item.Index).ImageIndex = item.Index
        End If
    Next

    newListView.View = View.LargeIcon
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

I have 96 values on `arr` consists of image path and only 82 of them gets to be displayed then the OOM error occured.

Maybe I misused the `Using` statement or anything. I hope you can help me with this. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, a hundred photos in your Pictures folder can easily consume a gigabyte or two of memory.  Kaboom when your app runs in 32-bit mode.  Resize the images so they don't need so much memory but are big enough for your ListView, dispose them after you added them to the ImageList, remove the jitter forcing so your program runs in 64-bit mode.

Comment: @HansPassant How can i dispose the images? and where can i put the dispose code? (sorry, beginner here). One more thing, you mean Resize by resizing the width and the height?

Comment: How large are your images? how many pixels? The way forward to resize the image to a thumbnail size suitable for your listview. Your listview doesn't need a megapixel image

Comment: @taoufik 3MB max i think.

Comment: Bitmaps in memory are uncompressed. You need to check the number of pixels and multiply that by 4 (number of bytes per pixel)... So: width x height x 4. A 4mb JPEG typically takes 12 megapixel times 4 = 38 mb in memory. And that times 80 images... 1.6 GB of memory

Comment: @taoufik wow, that's a lot! what should i do?

Comment: As I stated in the first comment, resize to a thumbnail large enough for your list view (in the range of 50x80 pixels or whatever the dimensions of your list view are). You can create the thumbnail on the fly (load the full image, resize it to a thumbnail, save the thumbnail in your arraylist and dispose off the full size image) or cached on the hard disk. More professional software typically cache thumbnails...

Comment: can anyone explain what is arr ?

Comment: @Hans Passant can anyone explain what is arr ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SOLVED] Creating a copy of the image and resizing the copied image to a bitmap thumbnail size then adding it to the ImageList(). After adding, dispose the original image and the bitmap copy.

I will post the code to help others who have the same issue.

```
    Dim item As New ListViewItem

    imageList.ImageSize = New Size(80, 100)

    For Each value In arr
        If System.IO.File.Exists(value) Then
            Dim buffer As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes(value)
            Dim stream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(buffer)

            Dim myBitmap As Bitmap = CType(Bitmap.FromStream(stream), Bitmap)
            Dim pixelColor As Color = myBitmap.GetPixel(50, 80)
            Dim newColor As Color = Color.FromArgb(pixelColor.R, pixelColor.G, pixelColor.B)

            myBitmap.SetPixel(0, 0, newColor)
            myBitmap = myBitmap.GetThumbnailImage(80, 100, Nothing, IntPtr.Zero)

            imageList.Images.Add(Image.FromHbitmap(myBitmap.GetHbitmap))

            myBitmap.Dispose()
            stream.Dispose()

            newListView.LargeImageList = imageList
            item = New ListViewItem(value)
            newListView.Items.Add(item)

            newListView.Items(item.Index).ImageIndex = item.Index
        End If
    Next

    newListView.View = View.LargeIcon
```

Where `arr` is the list of the image path directories.

Comment: can anyone explain what is arr ? list of the image path directories ?

Comment: Is arr means FileInfo() ?